# Convert Array to Json in angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var test=["a","b","c"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

I am stuck to doing this. i want output like this

```
{"a","b","c"}
```

But I am getting like this

```
["a","b","c"]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: {"a","b","c"} is a not valid JSON

Comment: `console.log('{' + test + '}');`

Answer (score 2):

Both JavaScript and JSON can represent data using a dictionary-style (as in objects using `{}` characters) or an array-style (a list of objects with the `[]` characters).

With dictionary-style objects:

- You use the `{key1:value1, key2:value2}` format
- You always have key and value for any entry
- `{"a":0, "b":1}` is valid
- `{"a", "b"}` is not valid

With an array:

- You use the `["a", "b", "c"]` format
- You only have values (and their position), no keys

So then, `{"a", "b", "c"}` is meaningless in both JavaScript and JSON.

You are defining an array in JavaScript:
`var test=["a","b","c"];`.
That is why the `JSON.stringify(test)` shows an array with `[]` and not an invalid syntax such as `{"a","b","c"}`.

Comment: Can you provide me some example?

Comment: There is no example that can produce the output `{"a", "b", "c"}`. It doesn't make sense to expect that since it's not a valid JSON format. If you want to see curly braces in the log, then you would define an object, something like `var test={"a":3, "b":4, "c":5}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an Array to JSON object but what you can do is create an object, store in it the array and then convert it.
something like this:

```
    var obj = {test: ["a", "b", "c"]};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```